# Rotate image on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this image rotate 360 degrees when it it hovered over, but it does not rotate and moves to a random location when it is hovered over.

I have tried changing its location on the page and adding a transform origin.

Any way to fix this?

```css
.bg-bean {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;
  transform: translate(48%, -40%);
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0));
  filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0));
  transition: transform .7s ease-in-out
}

.bg-bean:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-bean">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" >
</div>
```

Comment: you probably need to set a transform origin to 50% 50% if you want to rotate in place

Comment: You can rotate IMG only. https://jsfiddle.net/351yjxe6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```css
 .bg-bean {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 45%;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0));
    filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0));
    transition: all  .7s ease-in-out
}

.bg-bean:hover{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-bean">
    <img src="stylesimages/bean.png" width="100px" height="100px" >
</div>
```

Comment: Always use the snippet tool for js/css/html questions and answers. Please edit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?
I change the html just for testing purposes, and I added some comment in the code that I have changed.

```css
.bg-bean {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 45%;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0));
    filter: drop-shadow(20px 20px 20px rgb(0, 0, 0));
}

.bg-bean img {
    transform: translate(48%, -40%) rotate(0deg); /* I changed this */
    transition: transform .7s ease-in-out; /* I moved this */
}

.bg-bean:hover img {
    transform: translate(0) rotate(360deg); /* I changed this */
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-bean">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
img {
    transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/www-inside-design/uploads/2020/10/aspect-ratios-blogpost-1x1-1.png" width="100px" height="100px">
</div>
```

- on image CSS add `transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;`.
- on image hover CSS add `transform: rotate(360deg);`.